# How to return a default value for a property?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, default-value

I have the following Graphql type class including the POCO class: `Order.cs`.

Here I want to set the default value of each field. For example for `Name` I want to return "No Name" in case there is no value returned for it. In case of `Created`, I want to return today's date by default.

```
public class OrderType : ObjectGraphType<Order>
{
    public OrderType(ICustomerService customers)
    {
        Field(o => o.Id);
        Field(o => o.Name);
        Field(o => o.Description);
        Field(o => o.Created);
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public Order(string name, string description, DateTime created, string Id)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
        Created = created;
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; private set; }

    public string Id { get; private set; }
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using C# 6+, it has added [the ability to assign a default value to auto-properties](https://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2014/11/csharp-6-auto-property.html). So you can simply write something like this:

```
public string Name { get; set; } = "No Name";
public DateTime Created { get; private set; } = DateTime.Today;
```

This will set the default value of the `Name` property to `No Name` and the `Created` property to today's date, as you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. It worked for me :)